# How can the Interactive Brokers API C++ test socket client be built with VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Having followed the instructions given here http://www.interactivebrokers.com/php/apiUsersGuide/apiguide.htm#apiguide/c/using_the_c__testsocketclient_sample_program.htm
under Visual Studio Professional 2010, the c++ project always gives the following output:

```
1>  Generating Code...
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __initp_misc_invarg already defined in libcmtd.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __call_reportfault already defined in libcmtd.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __set_invalid_parameter_handler already defined in libcmtd.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __get_invalid_parameter_handler already defined in libcmtd.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in libcmtd.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl _invoke_watson(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?_invoke_watson@@YAXPBG00II@Z) already defined in libcmtd.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in libcmtd.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl _invalid_parameter(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?_invalid_parameter@@YAXPBG00II@Z) already defined in libcmtd.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: ___pInvalidArgHandler already defined in libcmtd.lib(invarg.obj)
1>     Creating library C:\Syncing\VCPlusPlus\IBTestSocketClientVS2010\Debug\SampleSocketClient.lib and object C:\Syncing\VCPlusPlus\IBTestSocketClientVS2010\Debug\SampleSocketClient.exp
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>C:\Syncing\VCPlusPlus\IBTestSocketClientVS2010\Debug\SampleSocketClient.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:01:30.63
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If anyone has had experience of this or understands how to fix this bug, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I guess I found the answer for you. I followed the indication of the error LNK2005 description and it indicates that there is some double linking thing happening behind the scenes.

The only thing you need to do is change the properties of your project Configuration:

```
Properties->Linker->Input->Ignore Specific Default Libraries
```

Here, you should set up the library you wanna ignore which is libcmt.lib. After setting up, you should see the value of **Ignore Specific Default Libraries** is:

```
libcmt.lib;%(IgnoreSpecificDefaultLibraries)
```

Then build, binggo~~~~ Please try it out.

Comment: Wenhao.SHE please take a look at the edits I made, I improved the formatting a little for you to make your answer more readable. Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for contributing!

Comment: Thanks lot. I am newbie here and I will try my best to write the neat answer in your formation next time. Thank you again!!:)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to fix your lib references. By the looks of below error, your project is referencing both the release and debug versions, hence the linker is not sure where to look for specific symbols as it is defined in multiple places (both debug and release):

> BlockquoteLIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: ___pInvalidArgHandler already defined in **libcmtd**.lib(invarg.obj)

In case you are not referencing any libs and the IB dll is doing it behind the scenes, you may want to explore the [NODEFAULTLIB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz4da4a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) option through your VS.

Comment: This sounds like the problem to me; through what menus would I have to navigate to de-reference either the release or debug symbols?

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0z8kac4.aspx) is probably what is being used in the VS2010 Interactive Brokers project.
My guess is setting [NODEFAULTLIB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz4da4a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) option through your VS 2010 can get rid of this.

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately this makes lots of `LNK2001` errors - `unresolved external symbol`; clearly the problem is lib references tho.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the PosixSocketClient code assumes that when compiled with a Microsoft compiler, Microsoft Foundation Library (MFC) is going to be used. Maybe it used to work like that in the past but I never got it working with VS2010. But I did get it working by removing dependency on/linking with MFC.

Unfortunately, code in `Shared` subfolder automatically assumes MFC if `_MSC_VER` is defined.
(`_MSC_VER` gives the version of Microsoft C++ compiler).
It cannot be simply `undef`-ined because some standard Windows headers use it.
This is clearly a bug as the presence of MFC is signalled by `_MFC_VER`, not `_MSC_VER`.
Therefore I had to change

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
```

everywhere in *EClientSocketBaseImpl.h* into

```
#ifdef _MFC_VER
```

Also, in file _StdAfx.h, `#include <afxwin.h>` should be wrapped additionally in a conditional compilation directive:

```
#ifdef _MFC_VER
#include <afxwin.h>
#endif
```